# calculating the ways of parenthesizing a boolean expression

Tags: algorithm, parentheses, catalan

Calculating the number of ways of parenthesizing a boolean expression. For example, a boolean expression I mean something like this, 1^0|0|1, for operator, it could be ^, & or |.

Did some reference and calculation, and it seems the number of ways is always (2n)!/((n+1)!n!), where n is the number of operators. If anyone have any ideas why the number of ways is always (2n)!/((n+1)!n!), appreciate for sharing the insights.

Here is an example about how do I mean different ways of parenthesizing, for example, the two different ways of parenthesizing both results in False.

1^((0|0)|1) 1^(0|(0|1))

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Edit the post to make it more clear.

Comment: It is not a programing question. Ask this on math.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of ways to fully parenthesize an expression is given by the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). By far the easiest way to understand why this is the case is using the following formula for the Catalan numbers:

[image: formula]

When there are 0 operators, there is only one way to fully parenthesize an expression: `(x)`.

When we have an expression with `n` operators, we can place the first operator in `n` places:

```
x|x       One operator, one possible location.
 ^

x|x|x     Two operators, two possible locations.
 ^ ^
```

When we 'place' an operator, we simply multiply the possible number of ways to parenthesize the left-hand side by the number of ways to parenthesize the right-hand side. We do this for every possible location, and sum those possibilities.

Comment: Thanks orlp, smart reply. A stupid question after study your reply and Catalan numbers -- why the ways of parenthesizing is related to the number of operator, other than the number of operands? :)

Comment: Another confusions is, when there are n operators, we should use Catalan number n or Catalan number n+1?

Comment: @LinMa That doesn't matter, `num_operands = num_operator + 1`. You can answer the second question yourself by simply counting the number of ways to fully parenthesize an expression with two operators and looking up that number in the Catalan series.

Comment: Thanks orlp. A dumb question, why Catalan number `C(n+1) = C0*Cn+C1*Cn-1+...+Cn-1*C1+Cn*C0`, other than `C(n+1) = C0*Cn+1 + C1*Cn +...+ Cn*C1 + Cn+1*C0`? In the latter formula, `0+(n+1) == 1+n == (n+1)`, but the former formula miss 1. It seems missing 1 is correct and wondering what is the logics behind the scene.

http://mathforum.org/mathimages/index.php/Catalan_Numbers

Comment: Hi orlp, if you could advise on my above question, it will be great. :)

Comment: @LinMa I believe I have answered this question sufficiently. I'm not a personal assistant. Make a new question if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks for all the help orlp. Mark your reply as answered. :)